# How to update public folder in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I use the command to create a laravel app and change the **welcome.blade.php**.

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel test-project 5.5
```

After that how to update the public folder?

I had tried the command but nothing changed.

```
npm run production
```

Comment: its not related to project public folder. It just build your style and scripts of your project. have a look https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/mix